# Swift nested generics

Tags: swift, generics

This is my playground:

```
class A {

    required init() { // in order to use X() this init must be required
    }

}

class B<X: A> {

    required init() {
        X()
    }

}

class C<X: A, Y: B<X>> {

    init() {
        Y() // Error here: 'X' is not a subtype of 'A'
    }

}

C()
```

Is that possible to have in Swift? What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

What I really want is this (Playground crashes with this code):

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MyEntity: NSManagedObject {}

class GenericCell<X: NSManagedObject>: UITableViewCell {

    func doSomething(entity: X) {}

}

class MyEntityCell: GenericCell<MyEntity> {}

class C<X: NSManagedObject, Y: GenericCell<X>>: UITableViewController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // here I should have Y = MyEntityCell
        tableView.registerClass(Y.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

}

C<MyEntity, MyEntityCell>()
```

Comment: I have no problem compiling that. Maybe some other part of your code is making problems?

Comment: @Sulthan can you try using any of the classes inside the code?

Comment: Done. See my answer.

Comment: @Sulthan I completely rewrote my playground. The error happens when I try to create an `Y` instance, do you have any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Added a solution with associated type. You should also report that compiler crash as a bug. The code shouldn't work but the compiler shouldn't crash while trying to compile it :)

Answer (score 1):

probably, what do you want, is not what are you doing ... please check this 'example'

```
class A {
    required init() {
    }
}

class B<X: A> {
    required init() {
        //X()
    }

}
class BB: B<A>{
    required init() {
        //B()
    }
}

class C<SomeUnknownTypeAlias, TypeAliasForGenericClassB: B<SomeUnknownTypeAlias>> {

    init() {
    }
    func foo(){
        dump(TypeAliasForGenericClassB)
    }
}

let c = C()
dump(c)
c.foo()
let cc = C<A,BB>()
dump(cc)
cc.foo()
/*
- C<A, B<A>> #0
- B<A> #0
- C<A, BB> #0
- BB #0
*/
```

or even simpler, because required init is not required at all there ..

```
class A {}
class B<X: A> {}
class BB: B<A>{}

class C<SomeUnknownTypeAlias, TypeAliasForGenericClassB: B<SomeUnknownTypeAlias>> {

    init() {
    }
    func foo(){
        dump(TypeAliasForGenericClassB)
    }
}

let c = C()
dump(c)
c.foo()
let cc = C<A,BB>()
dump(cc)
cc.foo()
```

ore even more generic, because B has no X requirements

```
class A {}
class B<X>{}
class BB: B<A>{}

class C<SomeUnknownTypeAlias, TypeAliasForGenericClassB: B<SomeUnknownTypeAlias>> {

    init() {
    }
    func foo(){
        dump(TypeAliasForGenericClassB)
    }
}
// here C type requirements must be specified!
let c = C<A,B<A>>()
dump(c)
c.foo()
let cc = C<A,BB>()
dump(cc)
cc.foo()
```

Comment: The compiler error shows up when I try to instantiate `TypeAliasForGenericClassB`. Try doing this: add `required init() {}` to `B` and `BB`, than change `dump(TypeAliasForGenericClassB)` with `TypeAliasForGenericClassB()`